# always starts from line 12

Tags: php, codeigniter

My project always starts from line 12. What could be the reason for this? I am using codeigniter in my project.

MyController.php

```
public function test()
{
   echo "test";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't reproduce here, https://3v4l.org/s5S0Q. Please provide larger MVCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought, is that you have line returns outside of your PHP tags.

for example

```
\n
<?php
```

Or

```
?>
\n
```

These will be output and can result in what you describe.  The end tags `?>` are optional.  Unless of course it's mixed with HTML.  Generally I never use them in pure PHP files.

These can appear in any files included by PHP prior to your output with `echo`.  They can be very difficult to find and can cause issues with things like redirects and some file downloads as well because of the output.  It's best to remove them.